# Are InputStream And OutputStream Buffered In Java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have a client-server program wherein I am using `InputStream` for reading from the `socket` (server) and `OutputStream` for writing into the `socket` (client). My server goes into sleep for 10 seconds every time it reads a `byte`. On the other hand, my client writes into the InputStream at full speed.

But what I observe is that after writing around 555,254 `bytes` into the `OutputStream`, the client is blocked at thr `write`() method of the output stream. My server, on the other hand, keep reading 1 `byte` at every 10 second interval.

Such behaviour is possible iff the data is being buffered on both the ends. Can someone please explain to me as to why this is happening? I am not using `BufferedInputStream` or `BufferedOutputStream`. Why is the data getting buffered?

Comment: The data is likely being buffered at a "lower" level.

Comment: You mean the TCP/IP buffers? Can you point me to some resource on this? Can I know the buffer size somehow? Thanks

Comment: Forgive my inexactness, but I'm not actually that versed in networking. Maybe the [`Socket.getReceiveBufferSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html#getReceiveBufferSize()) and [`Socket.getSendBufferSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html#getSendBufferSize()) methods can help you.

Comment: Oh, great hint. Thanks a lot.